# Tool to open apps automatically when internet / WLAN connection is established?

Tags: applications, internet

I'm searching for a tool that opens apps / programs when an active internet connection is established - or better: when the Mac is connected to a specified WLAN.

**Examples**

- On my way to work: no internet, no WLAN = nothing to do
- At work: internet access, "Work" WLAN = do not open chat program but open Mail automatically
- At home: internet access, "Home" WLAN = open chat program and Mail automatically

Does anybody know a simple tool that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context-aware actions are exactly what [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) was born to do. You give it rules for determining where you are and then actions to take when you reach certain locations or states. It's not the easiest program to wrap your head around but once you've got it tuned and your rules tested it works pretty well.